# Getting NPE while receiving the reply message using RabbitTemplate

Tags: spring-amqp

I have two microservices. one contains the REST controller which has the Get method which receives the message when sent to specific queue. other microservice just sends the reply message to same queue so that processed message can be seen in the browser when hit the REST API

however, getting NPE while receiving the message. 
below is the complete stack-trace:

```
2018-05-19 15:46:13.409  INFO 30104 --- [nio-8097-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/unit]   : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet' 2018-05-19 15:46:13.409  INFO 30104 --- [nio-8097-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started 2018-05-19 15:46:13.443  INFO 30104 --- [nio-8097-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 34 ms 2018-05-19 15:46:13.533  INFO 30104 --- [nio-8097-exec-1] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [35.154.27.134:5672] 2018-05-19 15:46:13.593  INFO 30104 --- [nio-8097-exec-1] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Created new connection: rabbitConnectionFactory#5b2b49d6:0/SimpleConnection@3e4f13fa [delegate=amqp://guest@35.154.27.134:5672/, localPort= 58742] 2018-05-19 15:46:18.681 ERROR 30104 --- [nio-8097-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/unit] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at com.infy.ci.unitamqpservice.UnitAmqpRestController.getAggregatedDataForSectionOfNightlyBuild(UnitAmqpRestController.java:83) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_151]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_151]
```

further, when hitting the REST API in the web browser, getting following log on the console

> 2018-05-19 15:45:22.328  INFO 30023 --- [           main]
>   o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean
>   'rabbitConnectionFactory': registering with JMX server as MBean
>   [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection:name=rabbitConnectionFactory,type=CachingConnectionFactory]
>   2018-05-19 15:45:22.423  INFO 30023 --- [           main]
>   o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase
>   2147483647 2018-05-19 15:45:22.445  INFO 30023 --- [cTaskExecutor-1]
>   o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to:
>   [35.154.27.134:5672] 2018-05-19 15:45:22.471  INFO 30023 ---
>   [cTaskExecutor-1] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Created
>   new connection:
>   rabbitConnectionFactory#325fc787:0/SimpleConnection@38a7acf7
>   [delegate=amqp://guest@35.154.27.134:5672/, localPort= 58736]
>   2018-05-19 15:45:22.875  INFO 30023 --- [           main]
>   s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s):
>   8099 (http) 2018-05-19 15:45:22.902  INFO 30023 --- [           main]
>   com.infy.ci.unitdbamqpservice.RPCServer  : Started RPCServer in 7.517
>   seconds (JVM running for 8.286) Sat May 19 15:45:23 UTC 2018 WARN:
>   Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is
>   not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+
>   requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit
>   option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using
>   SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need
>   either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set
>   useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate
>   verification. Sat May 19 15:46:13 UTC 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL
>   connection without server's identity verification is not recommended.
>   According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL
>   connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't
>   set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the
>   verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to
>   explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and
>   provide truststore for server certificate verification.

can this be the reason for NPE ? i have already included following in the JDBC code but still no luck.

```
prop.setProperty("useSSL", "false");
prop.setProperty("autoReconnect", "true");
```

both the services are checked-in at github:

- https://github.com/irfanjs/unitamqpservice
- https://github.com/irfanjs/unitdbamqpservice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return rabbitTemplate.convertSendAndReceive("myExchange", requestQueueName, message).toString();
```

You are unconditionally calling `toString()` on the reply.

The reply will be `null` if the template's `replyTimeout` is exceeded before the reply is received (the timeout defaults to 5 seconds).

You must check for  `null` result before calling `toString()`.

> just sends the reply message to same queue

You can't send the reply to the same queue - it must go to the `replyTo` header in the request.

If you use a `@RabbitListener` or `MessageListenerAdapter` on the server side, it will be taken care of for you.

This has nothing to do with SSL

> WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set.

That warning is about MySQL.

**EDIT**

I just hacked your applications down to the bare minimum and they work fine for me...

```
@Controller
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/application.properties")
@RequestMapping("/unittestdata")
public class UnitAmqpRestController {

    private final String requestQueueName = "rpc_queue1";

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UnitAmqpRestController.class);

    private final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public UnitAmqpRestController(RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate) {
        this.rabbitTemplate = rabbitTemplate;
        rabbitTemplate.setReplyTimeout(15_000L);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{projectid}/ut/aggregate",
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody String getAggregatedDataForSectionOfNightlyBuild(@PathVariable("projectid") int projectid,
            @RequestParam("buildtype") String buildtype, @RequestParam("build") String build) throws Exception {

        if (build.toLowerCase().equals("latest") && buildtype.equals("nightly")) {

            String message = String.format("aggregate");
            logger.info("Sending: " + message);
            Object returned = rabbitTemplate.convertSendAndReceive("", requestQueueName, message);
            logger.info("Reply: " + returned);
            if (returned == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException("failed to get a response");
            }
            return returned.toString();

        }
        else {
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

and

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource("classpath:/application.properties")
public class RPCServer {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RPCServer.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, TimeoutException, InterruptedException {
        SpringApplication.run(RPCServer.class, args);
    }

    private static final String RPC_QUEUE_NAME = "rpc_queue1";

    @Bean
    public Queue queue() {
        return new Queue(RPC_QUEUE_NAME);
    }

    @Component
    public static class RpcListener {

        @RabbitListener(queues = RPC_QUEUE_NAME)
        public String reply(String request) throws IOException, TimeoutException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
            logger.info(request);
            return request.toUpperCase();
        }

    }

}
```

and

```
2018-05-20 12:46:00.298  INFO 13369 --- [nio-8097-exec-1] c.i.c.u.UnitAmqpRestController           : Sending: aggregate
...
o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate      : Publishing message on exchange [], routingKey = [rpc_queue1]
2018-05-20 12:46:00.554 DEBUG 13369 --- [nio-8097-exec-1] o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate      : Reply: (Body:'AGGREGATE' MessageProperties [headers={}, timestamp=null, messageId=null, userId=null, receivedUserId=null, appId=null, clusterId=null, type=null, correlationId=null, correlationIdString=null, replyTo=null, contentType=text/plain, contentEncoding=UTF-8, contentLength=0, deliveryMode=null, receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, expiration=null, priority=0, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=, receivedRoutingKey=amq.rabbitmq.reply-to.g2dkABByYWJiaXRAbG9jYWxob3N0AAAHFAAAAAAC.3M1LyvOdR9dHQehSV4l67A==, receivedDelay=null, deliveryTag=1, messageCount=null, consumerTag=null, consumerQueue=null])
2018-05-20 12:46:00.561  INFO 13369 --- [nio-8097-exec-1] c.i.c.u.UnitAmqpRestController           : Reply: AGGREGATE
```

Comment: Thanks Gary> can you please tell me how to increase replyTimeout ? any documenttaion for the syntax please?                                                             further, do you suggest to remove toString() from the above line ? i tried to remove that , it is asking me to do the casting .... please suggest

Comment: further, i m already using @RabbitListener while replying the message. so i think replying to same queue does not matter. this is already been taken care of. Can you please suggest further ?

Comment: In that case, you are not sending a "reply message to the same queue". To change the timeout, see `RabbitTemplate.setReplyTimeout()`. If you are using Spring Boot, the property is `spring.rabbitmq.template.reply-timeout= # Timeout for sendAndReceive()` operations.` - see the [boot properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties).

Comment: Task1 : I added RabbitTemplate.setReplyTimeout() filed and set the time as 15000ms but still the same issue. NPE                                                        task2 : i verified the queue name is same in the send and receive phase.                                                                                                                     task3 : i verified all connections and are working fine. Mysql connection and rabbit host connection but still the issue                                      please help

Comment: You are **still** not checking for `null` before calling `toString()`. Why are you creating a connection factory and channel in the second service? You are not using them. The `@RabbitListener` looks ok so should work, as long as the service replies in time. I suggest you turn on DEBUG logging for both apps and follow the message flow on both sides to see what's happening. Add some DEBUG logging to your code too (both sides).

Comment: I just hacked your code to the bare minimum and it works fine for me (with a local RabbitMQ server). It seemed odd to me that you had no parameter on the listener so I added one (but it worked ok without it). See the edit to my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Let me check and come back soon